# Pardot - Sending emails via custom domain

Tags: pardot

I am having a little issue with a client

He does not like the fact that the exact target servers is visible to their customers

example 1 GMAIL :
[image]

Example 2 Outlook :

[image]

From what I have readed in an article it is a normal behavior, because it is the Pardot servers that send emails, so the emails are mailed by "PARDOT".

But I don't know if there is a way to make the Pardot servers not visible when sending those mails ?

this is the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313953&type=1) I have checked

Any help or recommendations would be much appreciated.

Note that our email sending domains are configured correctly & everything is perfectly fine.

Also Note that exact target server issue always existed in previous projects but there were no complaint at the time about it, and the photos shows two pics of different clients.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313465&type=1

Comment: @identigral Can I understand how this article is related to my issue ? because it talks about DNS management & keys set up, and I said it is done properly

Comment: If you had it configured according to this article, you wouldn't see Via... exacttarget.com in the mail header.

Comment: I dont understand how can that be possible, our SPF keys & DMkeys & DMpolicy keys are well verified, everything is in green, and still having this problem, for the second image especially, we don't see this problem in GMAIL or outlook web but only on Outlook desktop

Comment: You need to configure the domain in Pardot. In the new Pardot app, it's under Pardot Settings > Domain Management > Email Sending Domains. If you've done that and your domain is listed in there with green checks, then next step would be to verify this domain is actually used by Pardot when sending emails.

Comment: @identigral everything is with green checks, and I am using this domain to send email in the sending tab of the email template, but still get this problems

Comment: Open a support case with Salesforce. Pardot support has its own queue and they've been pretty responsive whenever we ran into issues at our clients.